# Stop Javascript event from affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, events

I have a script that creates an element, and part of the creation process is to add an onclick event (using addEventListener), but when I click a child element, the onclick event of the parent is triggered. How can I prevent the click from being detected when the source is a child element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation). This stops the bubbling of Javascript events and will only allow the events applied to the targetted element to execute;

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event){

    // event here

    event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the event is bubbling up to the parent.

In the child's `onclick` event, tell the event to stop propagation:

```
onclick = function (event) {
    // ...
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

the parent click handler: (check on the id of the clicked element)

```
function handler(e){
  if(e.target.id != "parentID") return;
  ....
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? There's a function built in that does it for you.

Comment: @Nile good point, but that has unlocked an issue I was hoping would be sorted by this question (as a side question really)

Comment: i don't prefer attaching a handler to every child element! just attach to the parent and check on the id !

Comment: What do you mean? You're still using a handler

Comment: Yes but a handler to only the parent not every child :)